# html; how to add a select drop-down to a form

Tags: forms, select, input

I'm wondering how I can add a select list to a from.  Here's my form

```
<form action="/myPath" id="frmSearch" method="post">

              <input id="AgeMaxTxBx" name="AgeMaxTxBx" style="width: 30px" type="text" value="120" />            


                <select id="country" multiple>
   <option value="China">China</option>
   <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
   <option value="United State">United State</option>
   </select>


                <a href="javascript:submitSearch()">submit Form</a>

            </form>
```

and here is the code that's parsing my form data:

```
 var formData = Request.Form;
        foreach (string key in formData.AllKeys)
        {
            string val = formData[key];
        }
```

I'm only seeing the "AgeMaxTxBx" key in my for loop.  I hope what I'm trying to do makes sense.  How might one accomplish this?  I would like to select multiple countries also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element needs to have a `name` attribute to be included in the `<form>` submit data, like this:

```
<select id="country" name="country" multiple>
```

Once you add this you'll see it in your keys.

Comment: Thanks, I should have seen that.